# Using C++ class objects between different blocks

Tags: c++, oop, object, dynamic, stl

I want to use C++ class object (declared in one block to) in another block. Is it possible to do so? Let me give you an example to be more specific:

I have a user defined function myfunc:

```
void myfunc()
{
   // ...
   if(condition is true)
   {
      myclass *ptr = NULL;
      ptr = new myclass // myclass is define somewhere else. Here I am creating an instance of it
   }

   if(another condition is true)
   {
       ptr = dosomething
   }

} // end of myfunc
```

Can I use ptr in the second if block?

Comment: Your actual problem aside, you shouldn't use raw pointers. Use a smart pointer.

Comment: To aid your Googling: the issue here is "variable scope".

Answer (score 5):

You can if you declare `ptr` outside the `if` block:

```
void myfunc()
{
   myclass *ptr = NULL;  // <= Declaration of ptr outside the block
   // ...
   if(condition is true)
   {
      ptr = new myclass    // myclass is define somewhere else. Here I am creating an instance of it
   }

   if(another condition is true)
   {
       ptr = dosomething
   }

} // end of myfunc
```

---

Also, I would suggest you to use [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Comment: The problem is I can't declare ptr right after entering the function (as per your input). The condition I am checking for is actually an XML tag and I want to create instance of class only when I encounter particular tag. So I will have to create an instance inside of if statement only

Comment: @user2812535 So, maybe the second condition should be inside the first `if` block? Because it should not be executed if the first condition is `false`...

Answer (score 1):

You can. Declare ptr outside of the first if block, and it will be visible in the second.

```
void myfunc()
{
   // ...
   myclass *ptr = NULL; // <-- moved here, it is visible within scope of myfunc
   if(condition is true)
   {
       ptr = new myclass;   
   }

   if(another condition is true)
   {
       ptr = dosomething
   }

} // end of myfunc
```